# Active class on inner tab

Tags: html, css, tabs, amp-html

I am trying to make tabs using this [link](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/tab_panels_with_amp-selector/).

I am able to make it. But, when I am doing nesting (tabs inside the tab content) I don't get expected output. I am not able to select inner tab automatically (when run code first time.) i.e. when I run my application "Tab one" is selected showing its content example "one div" and two tabs "inside tab one", "tab two". But I want to show "inside Tab one" as a selected tab and show it content "Tab one content"

Here is my [code](https://jsbin.com/zoroserube/edit?html,output):

```
<amp-selector role="tablist" layout="container1" class="ampTabContainer">
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" selected option="a">Tab one</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">
    <div>one div
      <amp-selector role="tablist" layout="container" class="ampTabContainer">
        <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="a">inside Tab one</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Tab one content... </div>
        <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="b">Tab two</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Tab two content... </div>
      </amp-selector>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="b">Tab two</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Tab two content... </div>
</amp-selector>
```

**Expected output looks like this when I run my application**

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-selector) you can't nest amp-selectors

> An `amp-selector` cannot contain any nested `amp-selector` controls.

You can create a tab using radio buttons and toggle between using the selected attribute and css opacity

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



::selection {
  background-color: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabbed > input {
  display: none;
}

.tabbed > label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabbed > label:hover,
.tabbed > input:checked + label {
  background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabs {
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.tabs > div {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tabbed">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

see [YozhEzhi](https://codepen.io/YozhEzhi/) codepen https://codepen.io/YozhEzhi/pen/gcLpI?editors=1100

Comment: can you suggest better solution  ..because in amp pages  js not work

Comment: how I will implement nested tabs

Comment: can we do this only using CSS

Comment: @user5711656 yes you can do it using some radio buttons as tab headers and some css

Comment: could you please provide me simple example